# 3 level repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a dynamic horizontal dynamic 3 level menu from a DB using repeater i can make the first level and then get stuck i dont know how to do it and whats the best quires to get the submenu and the subsubmenue...from the DB can any one help me  i used this for the first level...

```
     try
         {

             con.Open();
             reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

             List<menus> types = new List<menus>();

             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 types.Add(new menus() { ID = (int)reader["MenuID"], Name = reader["MenuName"].ToString(), page = reader["Page"].ToString(), Parent = (int)reader["Parent"],Order = (int)reader["Order"] });

             }
            rptlevel1.DataSource = types;
            rptlevel1.DataBind();
             con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             if (reader != null)
             {
                 reader.Close();
             }
             if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
             {
                 con.Close();
             }
             }
```

Comment: What are you having difficulties with exactly? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like the following:

```
repeater1_ItemDataBound
{
    //Get datasource for the current data item

    //Find child repeater control within this

    //Bind to the datasource
}
```

Repeat this for the second layer of repeater.

---

As for your comment - in this itemdatabound, find your second repeater and set it's itemdatabound event e.g.

```
rptOne.ItemDatabound += BindThirdRepeater;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've done so far is OK. Nest three repeaters and read the menu levels separately.

Read just the first menu level like you've done, then in the OnItemDataBound method of rptLevel1, do the same again read for second level menu items. Once more for level three and you're there.

```
1st level read

protected void rptLevel1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    2nd level read
}

protected void rptLevel3_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    3rd level read
}
```

Comment: ok but can you tell whats the query to bring the sub sub menu ....ive bring the first level using the menus with no parent but what about the sub sub

Comment: and how every menu will know its parent